# Algorithm to check if cylinders are overlapping in 3D

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I am creating a script to generate cylinders in a 3D space, however, I would like for them to not occupy the same region in space (avoid overlapping).

The cylinders are defined by a start and end point, and all have a fixed radius.

I am storing the existing cylinder in an array called `listOfCylinders` which is an nDim array of shape (nCylinders, 2Points [start, end], {x,y,z} coordinates of each point)

I was able to cook up:

```
def detect_overlap(new_start, new_end, listOfCylinders):
    
    starts = listOfCylinders[:, 0]
    ends = listOfCylinders[:, 1]
    radius = 0.1
    
    # Calculate the distance between the new cylinder and all the existing cylinders
    dists = np.linalg.norm(np.cross(new_end - new_start, starts - new_start), axis=1) / np.linalg.norm(new_end - new_start)
    
    # Check if any of the distances are less than the sum of the radii
    if np.any(dists < (2*radius)):
        return True
    
    # If no overlap or intersection is found, return False
    return False
```

But this is not accountting for situations where there is lateral overlaping.

Does anyone have a good algorithm for this?

Best Regards

Comment: The paper linked in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20610/how-to-determine-whether-two-cylinders-intersect-or-not appears to provide an algorithm. The only implementation I could find was in C++ [here](https://www.geometrictools.com/Samples/Intersection.html#IntersectCylinders)

Comment: here the start and end point are the 2 centres of the circles ?

Comment: @SrinjoyChoudhury. Yes, the start and end points are the centres of the circles

Answer (score 1):

WLOG one of the cylinders is vertical (otherwise rotate space). If you look at the projections of the apparent outline onto XY, you see a circle and a rectangle ended with ellipses. (For simplicity of the equations, you can also make the second cylindre parallel to XZ.)

If these 2D shapes do not overlap, your are done. Anyway, the intersection of a circle and an ellipse leads to a quartic equation.

You can repeat this process, exchanging the roles of the two cylinders. This gives a sufficient condition of non-overlap. Unfortunately, I am not sure it is necessary, though there is a direct connection to the plane separation theorem.

[image]

---

For a numerical approach, you can proceed as follows:

- move the cylindre in the canonical position;
- generate rectangles on the oblique cylindre, by rotation around the axis and using an angular parameter;
- for all sides of the rectangles, detect interference with the cylindre (this involves a system of a quadratic inequation and two linear ones, which is quite tractable);
- sample the angular parameter densely enough to check for no valid intersection.

I guess that a complete analytical solution is possible, but complex, and might anyway lead to equations that need to be solved numerically.

Comment: Nice one! Playing around with some graphics software for intuition I'm inclined to believe that this condition is indeed necessary (i.e. non-overlapping cylinders implies non-overlapping in at least one of those two projections).

Comment: Thinking a bit more about this, I wonder if your test is sufficient and necessary to test intersection between any shape formed by extruding a convex 2d shape (by *extrude* I just mean in the sense that a cylinder is an extruded circle).

Comment: After thinking some more I realized the test fails in cases where cylinders are parallel with one below the other (but not intersecting). In this case overlaps occur in both projections but the cylinders are non overlapping.

Comment: @jodag: quite right. So this is definitely a sufficient but not necessary condition. I tried to address the question with the parametric equations of one cylindre against the implicit equation of the other. This leads to two trigonometric inequations, one of which is quadratic. You'll have to solve a quartic equation and discuss the valid pieces.